# jenkins pipeline groovy - list box dependent on another listbox

Tags: jenkins, groovy, listbox, dependencies, jenkins-pipeline

I am alowed to define Jenkins pipeline just by editing a Jenkinsfile (stored in Git) and a predefinied shared library, written in Groovy.

For such a build I can use more datasets what are dependent on each other. Dataset A contains items what can be used as filter parameters from dataset B and so on. A parent-child relation.

So, it would be nice to have N listboxes (choices), already after hiting the "Build with Parameters" link and those listboxes to depend on each other. In the backgroud, a dedicated groovy script (from a shared library) would collect items for each corresponding listbox based on its parent item.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins was not built with that level of interactivity in mind, but you still can achieve that with two options.

One is to make your own front-end to the job that can change itself however you want. Once the final parameters are determined, you can trigger your job on Jenkins with "webhook trigger".

The other is to use ActiveChoice plugin.

Sometimes, to handle complex dependencies, your page would need to use JavaScript, and you would have to put that JavaScript in your page. For that, you need to write Groovy that generates that JavaScript. This is notoriously hard to write and to debug.